# Working with openssl RSA under MAC OSX 10.10 in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, encryption

I'm working on a simple class to encrypt and decrypt strings in xcode. Here's the code:

**.h file**

```
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

class rsa
{
    char * public_key;
    char * private_key;
    int padding = RSA_PKCS1_PADDING;

public:    

    //Constructors
    rsa();
    rsa(char *, char *);    

    // Methods
    unsigned char * public_encrypt(char *);

private:

    // Private Methods
    RSA * generate_rsa(bool public_key);
};
```

**.cpp file**

```
#include "rsa.h"

rsa :: rsa(char * public_key, char * private_key)
{
    this->public_key = public_key;
    this->private_key = private_key;
}

unsigned char * rsa :: public_encrypt(char * from)
{
    unsigned char * result;
    int encrypted_len;

    RSA *rsa = this->generate_rsa(true);
    result = (unsigned char *) malloc(RSA_size(rsa));

    RSA_public_encrypt(strlen(from), from, result, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);

    return result;
}

RSA * rsa :: generate_rsa(bool public_key)
{
    RSA *rsa = NULL;


    if(public_key)
    {
        BIO *keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf(this->public_key, -1);
        rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(keybio, &rsa,NULL, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        BIO *keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf(this->private_key, -1);
        rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(keybio, &rsa,NULL, NULL);
    }

    return rsa;
}
```

All I want to do is encrypt a string with my public key. But xcode says me that almost all openssl functions such RSA_public_encrypt and RSA_size are deprecated from OSX 10.7.

Here's my **main.cpp**:

```
int main()
{

    char * privateKey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"\
                    "MIGrAgEAAiEAy6uf9MPG6ohi/3pVEl3o/9NMZfKIMbhQbT09u6IQsd0CAwEAAQIh\n"\
                    "AKT8TWI4qc1ZWGC+V2W+fzwxjidtIwW3xZasDUlrlWodAhEA/bCcdSA0H/AmW/U0\n"\
                    "SXuhKwIRAM2GaSwJPLoenfzttkP+JRcCEQDdiq4XWtgqS/4zsB7JTT2hAhBAEM8G\n"\
                    "ABci+VpMNpljVnyfAhAlce8wS5CQF432ue8VUoMr\n"\
                    "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

    char * publicKey ="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"\
                   "MDwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADKwAwKAIhAMurn/TDxuqIYv96VRJd6P/TTGXyiDG4\n"\
                   "UG09PbuiELHdAgMBAAE=\n"\
                   "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

    char * test = "testestest!";

    rsa my_rsa(publicKey, privateKey);

    cout<<my_rsa.public_encrypt(test)<<endl;
}
```

This code won't work in xcode. I was expecting an hexadecimal output of my "testestest" string but the *result* buffer is blank. No errors, only a lot of warning on deprecation. Where I am wrong? What I am supposed to do? I've searched the web and openssl site but I could not understand how to do that.
Thank you for every suggestion.

Comment: The input string is "testestest!". I was expecting an hexadecimal output of my encrypted string but the _result_ string is blank. No errors, only a lot of warning on deprecation.

Comment: What makes you think an RSA raw binary encryption will be printable to the console ? You're likely (un)fortunate the encrypted data size is within the modulus size less the padding scheme requirement. Had the size requirements been larger than one frame this would have likely faulted outright. And... your leaking the bio's and `RSA*` keys allocated in your generate function.